# concatenate a string for all column values in sql update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a component table which has id, query columns. I want to concatenate a string type=bug to the query column for all values. Can it be done using update statement?

udpate dbname.tablename set query=query+"some_string", wiil this work?

Comment: Add some sample data to your question.  It's unclear what exactly you have in that column now and how you want it to look after the update.

Comment: What seems to be a problem here? How is it different from any other `UPDATE`?

Comment: udpate dbname.tablename set query=query+"some_string" . I do not want to specify where clause. Will that be okay? Want to update all data with a common string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you can do this with CONCAT(value, ' type=bug') at every field like :

```
UPDATE `col` SET `col1` = CONCAT(col1, ' type=bug'), SET `col2` ...
```

Comment: Why 1=1 in where clause?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONCAT(Id,' string') AS 'Column' FROM Table.
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = CONCAT(Id, ' string')

OR

SELECT (Id + 'string') AS 'Column' FROM Table.
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = (Id + 'String')